# .xls file is really wonky and refuses to obey Google and R

Tags: r, google-docs, xls

Trying to open data from government website ([hud.gov](https://www.hud.gov/RAD/resource-desk)) about Rental Assistance Demonstration: 
http://radresource.net/pha_data.cfm. 
The document appears to be an xls file but opening it in Google Docs failed so I tried R. Both readxl::read_xls and readr::read_tsv (as suggested [on GitHub](https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl/issues/374)) just gave me [this BS](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1btQdWn9XDYE0BxPoTAJd8WfmfnMYU7DCWBKf8a4BlqY/edit?usp=sharing) (Google Doc file or you can just download from radresource above). Any help would be muy apreciado!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something wrong with the files. I am also unable to open them with anything (excel, googledocs, R, etc.)